# pandas read_excel from ODS file locked by another user

Tags: python, excel, pandas, locked-files

I'm trying to retrieve csv-formatted data with pandas from a .ods file on a shared folder (mounted using nfs on my machine), and I have trouble getting the data when someone else is working on the file.

In that case, the file is locked, which makes perfect sense to avoid concurrent edition. One can see it when opening the file with LibreOffice for example, or just staring at the folder as a. .~lock file is present.

However, in my case, I'm just trying to open the file to read it with pandas, not edit it. Libre Office offers this possibility for instance. How is it pandas cannot provide that functionality ?

To be more precise, here is the command:

```py
sheet_df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name= "Sheet2", engine="odf", skiprows=3)
```

and the output

```py
File "/Users/user_name/job.py", line 148, in read_file
    sheet_df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name= "Sheet2", engine="odf", skiprows=3)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/virtualenv_prod/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/virtualenv_prod/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 364, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/virtualenv_prod/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1233, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/virtualenv_prod/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_odfreader.py", line 35, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/virtualenv_prod/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 420, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/virtualenv_prod/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_odfreader.py", line 46, in load_workbook
    return load(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/virtualenv_prod/lib/python3.9/site-packages/odf/opendocument.py", line 982, in load
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(odffile)
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1322, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I'm using python 3.9.2, on a MAC BigSur by the way.

Am I missing something, or pandas.read_excel cannot only read a file ?

Comment: It says "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" It seems that something else is the issue. Try creating a testfile and read that first. Then you know if it's file in use issue.

Comment: Well, it works when there is no lock on the file.. And the .ods file is not a zipfile, except if it turns out somehow into some compressed state when open/locked?